# В чем разница между функциями getch, getchar, scanf

Tags: c, c++

В чем разница между функциями getch, getchar, scanf в языке программирования C?

Comment: Ну это, тащемта, в названии, например.

Comment: Вообще-то это функции стандартной библиотеки, а не языка как такового. И в стандартной библиотеке С нет и никогда не было функции `getch`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) - форматированный ввод. Может прочитать за раз несколько значений разных типов и форматов (актуально для чисел с плавающей запятой)

[`getchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) - читает один символ из стандартного ввода (консоли). Если символ - EOF, то устанавливает флаг конца ввода для стандартного ввода ([`stdin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/)).

`getch` - просто читает один символ из консоли. В стандарт не входит, реализации для разных компиляторов могут отличаться. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235446.aspx) рекомендует использовать `_getch` из стандарта.

Comment: `getch` — это тяжёлое наследие `conio.h`. (И давайте обходиться без личных выпадов.)

Comment: > Петросян.

Непонятно, зачем задавать вопрос, ответ на который можно нагуглить за минуту.

Comment: Если вопрос о разнице между `getchar` и `getch` ещё имеет какую-то логику под собой, то уж вопрос об отличии `scanf` от них на мой вкус совсем странный. Список аргументов другой, возвращаемое значение другое, да вообще всё другое.

Comment: @Flammable, непонятно, зачем петросянить в ответе на вопрос, ответ на который можно нагуглить за минуту.

Comment: @Etki: потому, что автор вопроса поленился минуту погуглить?

Comment: "MSDN рекомендует использовать `_getch` из стандарта." Но в стандарте нет ни `getch`, ни `_getch`.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу [**getch** и **getchar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180001/what-is-the-difference-between-getch-and-getchar).

А вот отличия с scanf ищи в документации.